# Sunspot solr doesn't indexing all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, solr, sunspot

I have a model `Post`. Also I have STI model `Review`. Here is search config for `Post`:

```
searchable do
text :title, :content
text :username do
  user.try(:username)
end
text :user_full_name do
  user.try(:full_name_with_username)
end
text :user_full_name_with_username do
  user.try(:full_name_with_username)
end
```

end

The problem is, that not all models were indexed even if I add certain model through `Sunspot.index(Review.find(id))` and `Sunspot.commit`

After indexing, I trying to find some reviews by username :

```
reviews_ids = Review.search do
    fulltext params[:titles_search] do
      fields(:username)
    end
  end.results.map(&:id)
```

and there are not all reviews in results.

**What could it be? How to debug it?**

Answer (score 0):

The search results from Solr are always paginated so I suspect that you're not seeing all the results from your search. By default, I believe the results are paginated to 20 results per page.

To see all the search results at once you could do something like:

```
search = Review.search do
           fulltext params[:titles_search] do
             fields(:username)
           end
           paginate page: 1, per_page: Review.count
         end
```

This sets the "number of elements per page" equal to the number of total Reviews. So this should allow you to see all the search results without paging. Obviously if you have a large number of `Review` objects, this is going to be a huge memory hog.

A better way to do it is to work with the pagination behavior, so if you rewrite your search like this:

```
def search_reviews(opts = {})
  options = {
    page: nil,
    per_page: 20,
  }.merge(opts)

  Review.search do
    fulltext params[:titles_search] do
      fields(:username)
    end
    paginate page: options[:page] if options[:page].present?
    paginate per_page: options[:per_page] if options[:per_page].present?
  end.results
end
```

You can call it successively with different page numbers to get all your results.